# Compiling vulkan on raspberry

Tags: c++, raspberry-pi, vulkan

I am trying to use vulkan on raspberry pi 3 A+ (32-bit, Cortex-A53).

Raspberry OS:

```
pi@pi:~/Downloads/mesa_vulkan $ cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="10"
VERSION="10 (buster)"
VERSION_CODENAME=buster
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
```

I run this code on raspberry:

```
#include <vulkan/vulkan.h>

int main(void)
{

VkInstanceCreateInfo createInfo{};
createInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_INSTANCE_CREATE_INFO;
VkInstance instance;

VkResult result = vkCreateInstance(&createInfo, nullptr, &instance);

}
```

with these arguments:

```
g++ main.cpp -I ./VulkanFiles/ -L./VulkanFiles -lvulkan_radeon -lVkLayer_MESA_overlay -o ./CompiledFiles/main.out
```

where I have my vulkan header files in `VulkanFiles/Vulkan`

And I get:

```
in function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x38): undefined reference to `vkCreateInstance'
```

What I am unsure of, is if I use the correct library file(s). I use `libvulkan_radeon.so` which was downloaded using `sudo apt install mesa-vulkan-drivers`, as I saw in [this tutorial](https://www.ravbug.com/tutorials/rpi-vulkan/) (So I didnt compile the library on my own)

[image: vulkan raspberry]

1. Are `libvulkan_radeon.so` and `libVkLayer_MESA_overlay.so` the only library files I need to compile my main.cpp?
2. Where is vkCreateInstance() function stored? Maybe I am missing some libraries?|

Comment: Did you follow the Linux setup instructions?  https://vulkan-tutorial.com/Development_environment
You also need `sudo apt install libvulkan-dev` and possibly some other packages.

Comment: @jiveturkey I have not. Will check it, thanks.

Comment: A raspberry pi will very likely *not* have a radeon (AMD) video card. I also don't know if the vendor (Broadcam) actually ships a Vulkan driver. Without it you will be limited to doing stuff on the CPU.

Comment: @Botje is correct.  Unless you're targeting different hardware.  Anyway, that dev environment page shows you how to test if your hardware supports it.